# v-expansion-panel-content is showing <!----> on vue/test-utils

Tags: vue-test-utils

I am testing the veutify example v-expansion-panels using `"@vue/test-utils": "^1.1.4"`.

```
      <v-expansion-panels>
        <v-expansion-panel
          v-for="(item,i) in 5"
          :key="i"
        >
          <v-expansion-panel-header>Item</v-expansion-panel-header>
          <v-expansion-panel-content>
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.
          </v-expansion-panel-content>
        </v-expansion-panel>
      </v-expansion-panels>
```

But, after mounting my component, I am getting `<!---->` on the `<v-expansion-panel-content>`

```
    <div data-v-b60b777e="" class="v-item-group theme--light v-expansion-panels">
      <div data-v-b60b777e="" aria-expanded="false" class="v-expansion-panel"><button data-v-b60b777e="" type="button" class="v-expansion-panel-header">Item<transition-stub name="fade-transition">
            <div class="v-expansion-panel-header__icon"><i aria-hidden="true" class="v-icon notranslate mdi mdi-chevron-down theme--light"></i></div>
          </transition-stub></button>
        <transition-stub data-v-b60b777e="" name="expand-transition">
          <!---->
        </transition-stub>
      </div>
      ......
```

How do I make the content of the expansion panel to show up?

Answer (score 0):

Turns out I just need to add eager to the component like, `<v-expansion-panel-content eager>` which forces the content to be generated.